# Assign column with conditional values based on strings contained in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I am trying to assign a column based on strings that may be contained in other columns. For example

```
var1 = 67

columns = {'col1': ['string1', 'thang2', 'code3', 'string2'], 
          'col2': [1, 2, np.nan, 3], 'col3': ['I', 'cant', 'think', 'what']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = columns)
```

How do I then make a fourth column `col4` that is `col3 + var1 + col1` most of the time, but is `np.nan` whenever `col2` is `nan` (in the same row) and has a `-W` appended to its value whenever there is an `'in'` in any the string in `col1` (again, in the same row)?

I know all about `assign`, but I don't know how to do all that conditional stuff in the assign, or if there is a way to do it after creating the column, I'm not sure either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this using `np.where`:

```
df['col4'] = np.where(df['col2'].notnull(),
                      df['col3'] + str(var1) + np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('in'),
                                                        df['col1'] + '-w',
                                                        df['col1']), 
                      np.nan)
```

Output:

```
      col1  col2   col3             col4
0  string1   1.0      I     I67string1-w
1   thang2   2.0   cant     cant67thang2
2    code3   NaN  think              NaN
3  string2   3.0   what  what67string2-w
```

Or if you want to do it with `assign`:

```
df.assign(col5 = np.where(df['col2'].notnull(),
         df['col3'] + str(var1) + np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('in'),
                                           df['col1'] + '-w',
                                           df['col1']), 
         np.nan))
```

Output:

```
      col1  col2   col3             col4             col5
0  string1   1.0      I     I67string1-w     I67string1-w
1   thang2   2.0   cant     cant67thang2     cant67thang2
2    code3   NaN  think              NaN              NaN
3  string2   3.0   what  what67string2-w  what67string2-w
```

Update: Since you mentioned speed. I think I'd remove the .str accessor and use list comprehension too.

```
df['col4'] = np.where(df['col2'].notnull(),
         df['col3'] + str(var1) + np.where(['in' in i for i in df['col1']], 
                                           df['col1'] + '-w', 
                                           df['col1']), 
         np.nan)
```

Comment: Which one would be faster? This particular df has about 30 million rows, so speed is somewhat a factor.

Comment: The first should be faster.

Comment: Nested `where` is always underrated. My tests show it is actually faster than np.select for upto 3 levels of nesting. +1